# Hibernate native SQL error

Tags: oracle, hibernate, ora-00904

I am trying to execute sql native query using hibernate 3.3.2.GA.

I have following query.

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT {dept1.*}, {dept2.*} FROM Dept d1, Dept d2 WHERE d1.deptId = d2.deptId").
   addEntity("dept1",com.test.pojo.Dept.class).
   addEntity("dept2",com.test.pojo.Dept.class).
   list();
```

Mapping file for Dept class is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.test.pojo.Dept">
  <id column="deptId" name="deptId" type="long">
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <version name="version" access="field" column="version"></version>
  <property  name="deptName" type="string" column="deptName"/>

  <set name="emps" cascade="all" inverse="true">
     <key column="deptId"></key>
     <one-to-many class="com.test.pojo.Emp"/>
  </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But why I get following error? It is converting my query to

> SELECT **dept1.**deptId as deptId1_0_, **dept1.**version as
>   version1_0_, **dept1.**deptName as deptName1_0_, **dept2.**deptId as
>   deptId1_1_, **dept2.**version as version1_1_, **dept2.**deptName as
>   deptName1_1_ **FROM Dept d1, Dept d2** WHERE d1.deptId = d2.deptId.
>
> Hibernate: SELECT dept1.deptId as deptId1_0_, dept1.version as
>   version1_0_, dept1.deptName as deptName1_0_, dept2.deptId as
>   deptId1_1_, dept2.version as version1_1_, dept2.deptName as
>   deptName1_1_ FROM Dept d1, Dept d2 WHERE d1.deptId = d2.deptId
>   20:43:41,109 WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 904,
>   SQLState: 42000 20:43:41,109 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 -
>   ORA-00904: "DEPT2"."DEPTNAME": invalid identifier

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2235)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1723)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175)
    at com.test.test.Test1.main(Test1.java:96)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "DEPT2"."DEPTNAME": invalid identifier
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:590)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1973)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteDescribe(TTC7Protocol.java:850)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteQuery(OracleStatement.java:2599)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2963)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:658)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:584)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1812)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
 session.createSQLQuery(
     "SELECT {dept1.*}, {dept2.*} FROM Dept dept1, Dept dept2 WHERE dept1.deptId = dept2.deptId")
     .addEntity("dept1",com.test.pojo.Dept.class)
     .addEntity("dept2",com.test.pojo.Dept.class)
     .list();
```

If you was misled by the documentation ([18.1.4. Returning multiple entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17380)), there is a bug there ([HHH-2976](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2976)), feel free to vote for it.

Comment: I think d1.deptId and d2.deptID should also be modified to dept* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try Google with the ORA-XXX codes. From http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00904_string_invalid_identifier.htm

> Question:  I am running a SQL
>   statement and I get a SQL*Plus error
>   ORA-00904 invalid identifier.
>
> Answer: When ORA-00904 occurs, you
>   must enter a valid column name as it
>   is either missing or the one entered
>   is invalid. The "invalid identifier"
>   most common happens when you are
>   referencing an invalid alias in a
>   select statement.  The Oracle docs
>   note this on the ORA-00904 error:

Comment: No, the problem is Hibernate converting query to invalid. I am refering hibernate-reference documentation.